# jquery ajax not working

Tags: jquery, asp.net

```
$.ajax(
 {
   type: "POST",
   url: "chatwindow.aspx/getLstMesgs",
   data: "{lgUserId:" + getParameterByName("id") + ",time:'" + time + "'}",
   contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
   dataType: "json",........
```

I am using the above code... when i run the code it is not posting... in firebug it show 500 internal error

Comment: Look in Firebug what you're posting to the server and then run that through JLit to see if your JSON is valid.

Comment: Look inside the error row, you can see the returned HTML on the HTML tab. It will be an asp.net error page.

Comment: the json is valid.. i am using dotnet 4.0 , its just a call to a web method using jquery... is it to do anything with 4.0

Comment: resolved..thnx all... thx Elad i checked in html tab.. it displayed there was type mismatch of the parameters

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A 500 would mean that it is POSTing, but there's an error on your server.

Comment: resolved..thnx all... thx Elad i checked in html tab.. it displayed there was type mismatch of the parameters